# Create same effect in Illustrator as Carhartt image below

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography

I've tried using the roughen tool in illustrator but not really getting the results I'm looking for. Any advice would be much appreciated.[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you show an example of what you have tried to demonstrate why roughen isn't achieving the effect you want?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As asked above, I can't answer why the effect isn't working for you without examples of what you have tried.

However, while looking for something else today, I did find this font that looks just like the effect you are trying to replicate.  If you register with Creative Market, it is one of the free items for this week.

[Calderock](https://creativemarket.com/Martype.Co/2713671-Calderock-Typeface-Extras)

[image: Example]

the blurry effect on the edge however is from the rasterizing of the text.  You might be able to accomplish that with a feathering effect.

Answer (score 1):

After some trying, I reached this result.

I used:

- Roughen
- Gaussian Blur
- Rasterize
- Stamp

See the image below for the reference values I used.

[image]